# How do I load multiple json arrays based on ng-route?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, angular-services

I'm fairly new to angular and I am wondering if there is a way I can load multiple json arrays into my app. Basically, I have a json document that contains data that looks kinda like this example.

It has multiple arrays within the same file. I was thinking that maybe I could loop through them and load the data, but I'm not sure.

```
{
    'title': 'myApp',
    'data1': [
        {
            'listname': 'name1',
            'id': '1'
        },
        {
            'listname': 'name2',
            'id': '2'
        },

    ],
    'data2': [
        {
            'listname': 'name1',
            'id': '1'
        },
        {
            'listname': 'name2',
            'id': '2'
        },

    ],
    'data3': [
        {
            'listname': 'name1',
            'id': '1'
        },
        {
            'listname': 'name2',
            'id': '2'
        },

    ]
}
```

I found a service to load the data like this.

```
app.factory('grabData', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        get: function(callback) {
            $http.get('data/names.json').success(function(data) {
                callback(data);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

My controller looks like this below and I don't want to load each data like this. Is there a way I can switch the arrays based on the route instead of loading it one by one? As you can see below, this is not the best way I am doing it.

```
grabData.get(function(data){
     $scope.thedata = data;

     $scope.myTotal1 = data.data2.length;
     $scope.myList1 = data.chapter1;

     $scope.myTotal2 = data.data2.length;
     $scope.myList2 = data.data2;

     $scope.myTotal3 = data.data3.length;
     $scope.myList3 = data.data3;

     $scope.myTotal4 = data.data4.length;
     $scope.myList4 = data.data4;
});
```

You see where this is going.  data5, data6, etc.

I have my routes set up and if I could somehow load them based on the routes I have, then that would work good, I suppose.

Comment: there are quite a few things wrong here;  Firstly, if you are using a single controller for multiple pages/routes (as it appears you might be), that is a really bad practice.  Secondly, why would you need to re-assign the values you have again? if you have `$scope.thedata`, then `$scope.thedata.data1.length` would be exactly the same as `$scope.myTotal1` as defined here, so the extra assignments don't quite make sense.

Comment: ok. so how can I assign those different arrays without the extra variables?

Comment: what do you mean "how can you assign them"? ***they are already assigned***

Comment: it's not really clear what this data is supposed to represent, or why you would be loading data for multiple pages in a single API call;  It's also not clear what you plan to do with the data once it's been assigned to all these variables.  Perhaps if you could try to show a bit more about what you are trying to accomplish, it might be easier to sort out.

Comment: I know they are already assigned. What I mean is how can I access each array without defining it multiple times? I am loading different arrays with ng-repeat.

Comment: what's wrong with using `$scope.thedata.data1`?  again, it's not really clear why you would even be getting data that doesn't belong to the route you are on in the first place.  `ng-repeat="item in thedata.data1"` would give you the same result as the assignment and then doing `ng-repeat="item in myList1"`....  as far as the intent of your pseudocode here goes, anyway.

Comment: True, thats what I have so far. The question is instead of using `ng-repeat="item in thedata.data1", ng-repeat="item in thedata.data2", etc`. Can I make those values dynamic?

Comment: yes, you could make them dynamic.  but you *still* are avoiding the question of **why** you are receiving the data this way in the first place, and why you are using the same controller for multiple views.

Comment: you're not saving yourself anything by doing it this way, you're still making an API call on every route change, but fetching a large amount of data that you will probably never use each time.

Comment: I am only using this for one view

Comment: That's not what your question says, it specifically asks how to load the data based on your route, which implies multiple views.

Comment: i am using the route to determine which data to show.

Comment: and each route is a separate view.  you may be *trying* to use the same template and same controller for this, but that's not the right approach.  if you have a template that is only showing one list, then the controller should only load one list.

Comment: from what you seem to be describing now, when you go to `http://example.com/data1`, you are loading `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, etc. but never using most of them.  when you switch to `/data2`, you'll *make another* server call, and retrieve `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, etc ***again***, and still only use one of them.  This design is flawed.

Comment: Yeah, thats it. So should I make a controller for each set of data instead of loading them all into the view?

Comment: there are a couple ways to handle this; the data appears to be a json document, does that mean that this will never change?

Comment: Correct. It will not be changing. I have entered all the data.

Comment: ok I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish a bit clearer now, I'll try to put together an answer to how I would approach this.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I tried unsuccessfully to set up a plunker that worked, unfortunately; but what I would do, basically, is use `/:dataPath` in the route, and use `thedata[$routeParams.dataPath]` to isolate the data you are after.

Comment: This is really clever. I actually didn't think about passing the route into the array. Thanks for everything!

Comment: I have much more clarity about loading data in the view.

Comment: I would also load your data into a service; services are singletons, so you can fetch the data once, then inject it into the controller each time, saving the redundant server trip.